# php : Sort 2 values of data by order alphabetical

Tags: php

In one data I have a field title and field name ( field name is the name of a pdf file uploaded, for ex : My_file.pdf and title field is like an override for the front end, a null field)

I want to sort the data in alphabetical order taking into account the name field and the title field

Actually i tried to sort only by name like this :

```
                usort($filesContent, function($a, $b) {
                    return strcmp($a->getName(), $b->getName());
                });
```

But now I'm stuck, I don't see how to add a filter on the title

can someone guide me to solve my problem ? thanks

Comment: FYI: Sorting and filtering, are two different things. You are asking about sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could concatenate both name and title into one string and compare... This would work for files with same filename but different titles. However this may have a weird effect with some data.

```
      usort($filesContent, function($a, $b) {
          return strcmp($a->getName().$a->getTitle(), $b->getName().$b->getTitle());
      });
```

You'd best sort by name first, then if the comparison is returning 0 meaning they are the same, sort by title.

```
      usort($filesContent, function($a, $b) {
          $nameSort = strcmp($a->getName(), $b->getName());
          if($nameSort == 0) return strcmp($a->getTitle(), $b->getTitle());
          return $nameSort;
      });
```

Comment: thanks you, this could work if a data have a title AND a name ?

Comment: Yes indeed. Sorting by name and then by title, you can change the getters accordingly if you want the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

You callback function can do whatever you want. It only return value that matters. You need to return `-1` when `$a` is "smaller" (whatever that means for you) than `$b`, `1` if `$a` is "greater" than `$b` or `0` if both are equal. So you basically with two sort keys, you sort by first and if you got `0` then you sort by second key.

```php
usort($filesContent, function($a, $b) {
   $result = strcmp($a->getName(), $b->getName());
   return $result === 0
        ? strcmp($a->getTitle(), $b->getTitle())
        : $result;
});
```